# Array contains string the other way

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have this array

```
const urlList = ["/user/profile", "/user/edit", "/verify/device"];
const isContainUrl = fruits.includes(window.location.pathname);
```

That is fine if pathname is static like above, what if I have url like `/verify/device/{device-id}` , I want isContainUrl to be true as well for partial match. But since I am comparing longer string to the shorter one, so I cant simple use indexOf.

May be anyone has any idea to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check both edge cases:

```js
const urlList = ["/user/profile", "/user/edit", "/verify/device"];
const veryLongString =  '/verify/device/1';

const isContainUrl = urlList.some(s => s.includes(veryLongString) 
    || veryLongString.includes(s));
console.log(isContainUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse url according to custom rules, or do some regular matching work.

Refer to [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp).